# JavaScript validation from field values

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am trying to set a min/max validation, where the max value is called from another field, if I type the min-max value the code works, but if I add the getField function then the alert is always triggered.

Must the value be formatted?

```
event.rc = true;

if (event.value != "" && event.value != this.getField("Max projection").value && event.value 
!= "350")

{
app.alert("The entered value needs to be more than '100' or less than'350'! and 25cm less than 
width ");
event.rc = false;
}
```

Comment: As far as i know, the field cannot have 'space' in it. Whats the name of your field?

Comment: The field name is Max projection. I have just tried again with an underscore in the filed name and the script, but still flagging up with the alert.

Answer (score 0):

All working now and with colour warning :-)

```
event.rc = true;
if (event.value >= 150 && event.value <this.getField("9 Awning 
Width").value-24) 

{ event.target.textColor = color.black; } else { app.alert("The entered 
value needs to be between 150 & max 300cm! or Width minus 25cm, which ever 
is lesser"); event.target.textColor = color.red; }
```